# How to calculate the width of a <div> tag for example based on characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, fonts

I need to create a  tag that is absolutely positioned with a variable width, based on the string length, font, size...

Ex.:

```
<div>hello</div>
```

For this I would need about 50px of width. How to calulate this in Javascript?
thanks

Comment: Did you try using jQuery's width() function? It always returns the content width: http://api.jquery.com/width/ --> $('div').width()

Comment: See my answer... for some reason everyone assumes JavaScript == jQuery *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jesus you guys, JavaScript !== jQuery. Anyways, to get a width of an element with JavaScript you can use `offsetWidth` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/gJyKV/1/

(code)

```
document.getElementById('test').offsetWidth
```

If will get the current width even if it's absolutely positioned!

Comment: exactly what I needed. it seems to be crossbrowser too, right?

Comment: wow oscar you got me man i just dont like it all the people when some one ask a javascript question they answer with the f jquery i just need to say it laud sorry 
I Haaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaate jquey 
howwwwwwwwwwwwwwaaaa 
:@@@@@

Comment: Indeed. ctrl/cmd+f for offsetWidth here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Comment: I personally love jQuery, but you dont always need it and a lot of times you dont want to use it. Such cases are building API wrappers or JS libraries.

Comment: i don't mind playing with jquery but sure if i'm in hurry or i reached a dead end with js although if i give it some time i will reach with js

Comment: People who *really* use jQuery use it so they can get more done faster. You can obviously do whatever in jQuery in raw JS (duh), but the point is to not waste time on stuff that doesn't matter, like cross browser attribute removal, or, DOM selection (technically Sizzle), or even cross browser AJAX. I personally would rather spend that time making cool stuff then getting this XHR req workin the same in all the browsers. I mean, it's why all big sites use libraries like Google, Twitter, etc :)

Answer (score 1):

Create the text in a span, measure its rendered width, and then re-position it to taste. You can always render it off-screen and then re-position if you don't like the jump in position.

http://jsfiddle.net/vW6Wp/

```
var test = $('<span>hello</span>').appendTo('body');
alert(test.width());
```

Comment: that's nice! thanks. without jquery is there any other way? thx

Comment: Yes, you can create the span via the DOM, append it to the body, and then use elem.offsetWidth. It's just terser in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the jQuery library also offer this. If you gave this div the ID 'get-width' the following could would give back the width:

```
$('#get-width').width();
```

You could give it a should by testing it with the following code:

```
<div id="test">hellloooo</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#test').width());
  }
</script>
```

Comment: on a div it gives me the 100% width. if i use a span it works, but in my case i need to apply it on a div...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why always people answer things with jquery ' is jquery is a standard for scripting language and if the guy need that item alone about the width of the div to load all that script . 
there is something called javascript guys .

sorry for this big talk but i just dont like it

@tooty
you can get that with javascript by catching the div by id and then get the offsetWidth

```
document.getElementById('divId').offsetWidth
```

Regards

Comment: i wish we all prefer it you know i sow many guys just when they see a junior developer dont know js just tellem just learn jquey 0_o what the f does jquery shit is all about i just hate it people should learn the core things first

Comment: @Tooty woooow at last i found some one think as i do i just looked at your profile and know how much you like js pure i would like to be a friend man :)

Comment: add me to facebook ;) http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100001290352210 we can talk someday

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do complex calculation, just use [this](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/dom-width-height.php) (Dom way of getting the width of an element).

As you can see, way to complex as each browser has a different way to do it. that is the drive that made [Mootools](http://www.mootools.net/docs) and the other JavaScript libraries into life in the first place. Do yourself a favor and use one of those libraries.
[Here is the Mootools way](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Dimensions).